# Почему RequestDispatcher не перебрасывает на выбранную страницу?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Мне нужно чтобы сервлет переправил пользователя на указанную страницу. Для этого использую

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/demo/new.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Однако меня на эту страницу не перекидывает. Используя

```
resp.sendRedirect("/demo/new.jsp");
```

- все работает. Однако мне нужно будет получать некоторые данные сессии. Почему getRequestDispatcher не заводится?

Answer (score 1):

`request.getRequestDispatcher("...").forward(...)` выполняет *внутреннее* перенаправление, т.е. сервер внутри себя передаёт дальнейшую обработку запроса указанной странице. При этом клиент (браузер) ничего об этом не знает.

`response.sendRedirect("...")`, наоборот, выполняет внешнее (клиентское) перенаправление, т.е. сервер как бы говорит клиенту: "чтобы получить страницу, которую ты запрашивал, перейди по такому-то адресу", после чего браузер меняет адрес в адресной строке и запрашивает у сервера страницу по этому новому адресу.

Comment: Это описание методов, но не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @parkito Тогда уточните вопрос. Вы спросили, "почему RequestDispatcher не перебрасывает?", я ответил, что он и не должен.